# c++ - return ((fileatr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0);

Tags: c++

I'm trying to check to see if a file exists but the last part of my code gives me this error:

> unsigned long (__stdcall*)(void) at memory location 0x006FF74C.

```
bool checkfile(char* filepath) {

    static DWORD __stdcall fileatr = GetFileAttributes(filepath);

    if (fileatr = INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {

        throw GetLastError;
    }
    return ((fileatr &  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0);    
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is expected with this code.  Consider `throw GetLastError();`, you'll have to `catch (int& winerr)`.  The added `()` is essential to actually call the function and retrieve the error code.

Comment: Note that `fileatr = INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` will set fileatr to that value, and if that value is not zero, will execute the body of the if, which does a throw of the memory address of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed 2 things as mentioned Hans and Eljay.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

bool checkfile(TCHAR* filepath) {

    DWORD fileatr = GetFileAttributes(filepath);

    if (fileatr == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) { // fixed. (= mean assign, == mean compare)
        throw GetLastError(); // fixed.
    }

    return ((fileatr &  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0);
}

int main()
{
    try {
        checkfile(_T("test.not.exist.txt"));
    }
    catch (DWORD lasterror) {
        std::cout << "catch GetLastError() : " << lasterror << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```